spring-docs implementation with beans
I am a newbie in spring boot framework and I am curious how spring-docs can detect the GroupedOpenApi. From spring-docs documentation I know that I need to have configuration like below:
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi licenseV1Api() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group(v1-api")
                .pathsToMatch("/v1/**")
                .build();
    }

}

I would like to know how sping-docs use that bean in it's core.
I want to know how spring-docs detect and use GroupedOpenApi bean
